# How to make a power switch using MOSFETs?

Tags: power, mosfet, switching, nmos

[image]

I am stumped on trying to create a circuit that, through an enable of 3.3V will let +18V go to the load or prevent it from doing so. This is my current approach. I know the pullup resistor should not be pulled from the source but I thought that we could use voltage division to mitigate that. I don't believe this is the most efficient way to do this so I turn to you all for some help.

Is there another circuit that can perform the same thing but better, or is there something I can do to improve what I've come up with?

[image]

Comment: please draw schematics to convention ... V+ at top ... GND at bottom ... input on one side ... output on other side ... rotate the schematic diagram counter clockwise 90 degrees .... then flip Q2 vertically ... you can use the schematic editor that is built into this website ... click `save and insert` when completed

Comment: Is the 18V stable or fluctuates in some range? Divider can help you to maintain Vgs of Q2 in safety zone. Or you can use a zener between G and S.

Comment: R4 is not "well wired".

Comment: In your improved schematic don't you want R4 connected from the 18 V line to the Gate of Q2?

Comment: Depending on the circuit providing the "enable" signal, you might be able to eliminate R2 and R1.  Most power MOSFETs are rated for 20 V Vgs, so the R2-R5 attenuator is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly efficient way of pulling it off. Q1 can of course be tiny. Q2 needs gate and pull-up resistors in any case so sizing them to perform voltage division doesn't incur any penalty in extra parts.

Unsurprisingly, you can get monolithic chips that will have all this in one package but unless you are strapped for board space it's probably not worth it.

Comment: I've heard that the 10K pull up resistor connecting Q2 gate and source will pull gate's value up to match source. Is it something that is allowed, or am I reading too much into everything.

Comment: That's how you turn Q2 off. For PMOS, gate voltage needs to be pulled negative relative to the source to make the transistor conduct. You need to size R5 and R3 to keep Q2's gate voltage from going *too* negative, however. Right now, it's going to be around -15V.  Take a look at your transistor's datasheet and compare that to the Vgs(max) value.

Comment: Would the gate's voltage not be based on R3? Thats also another concern, Vth is Min -2, Max:-3.5 and typ -2.5. With the current voltage division I have, assuming we are measuring voltage through R3, when Q1 is off VGS=-3.52 and when on VGS=-3.

Comment: The voltage *across* R3 should be ~3V when Q1 is conducting and essentially 0V when Q1 is cutoff, so make sure Q1 can handle at least 18 Vds. The threshold voltages given are usually for microamps of Ids so they cannot be taken as a reliable indicator of useful current, you need to look at the Ids/Vds/Vgs curves from the datasheet.